# What, precisely, does "reset network settings" do on an iPhone?

Tags: iphone, network, wifi

I use "internet sharing" on my Mac, but lately I've been having trouble connecting my iPhone 5 to the resulting WiFi network. I've read advice online to do `Settings -> General -> Reset -> Reset Network Settings` on the iPhone, but I can only find very vague information on what this actually does. From the name it sounds like a bit of a nuclear option, and before I try it I want to make sure that it's not going to affect my ability to use the cellular network.

So, does the iPhone's "reset network settings" just reset WiFi settings, or does it reset cellular network settings as well? If the latter, is there any danger that this would delete any settings installed by my phone company, causing problems with using internet or telephone services via the 3G or 4G networks?

Answer (score 21):

According to [this Apple support page](https://www.apple.com/support/iphone/assistant/wifi/#section_5),

> This will clear your current cellular and Wi-Fi network settings,
>   including saved networks, Wi-Fi passwords, and VPN settings.

So, it will reset your network connection options, and **it will affect internet connectivity**, both GSM/GPRS/EDGE/3G/4G and WiFi, but it shouldn't impact "classic" telephone services, because they are usually auto-configured by the carrier and do not require specific settings on the mobile phone.

Comment: In IOS 9, the WiFi networks, but not the VPN accounts are also cleared in any Macs sharing the same iCloud account.

Comment: What @DavidVeksler said is true, and important: **resetting network settings will remove all saved WiFi passwords in iCloud keychain**, effectively deleting remembered WiFi networks from **all your signed in devices**. A workaround: turn off iCloud Keychain, then reset network settings, then turn iCloud Keychain back on. Your saved WiFi networks will then sync back, unharmed.

Comment: Note that WiFi passwords will only be deleted from the **iCloud** keychain on your Mac. The WiFi passwords stored in the **System** keychain will remain, but they will no longer be synced to iCloud.