# Does "Reset Network Settings" affect all devices?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, network, wifi

If I reset my Network Settings in iOS/iPadOS, and so lose all my WiFi networks/passwords, will my other iOS devices also lose them?

The reason I ask is that WiFi networks appear to be stored in the cloud (when one is entered into my iPhone, my iPad also seems to learn it). So if I erase my iPhone... will the ones in the cloud be forgotten? Or will my iPhone pull them back from the cloud?

Answer (score 4):

- [What, precisely, does "reset network settings" do on an iPhone?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/90506/what-precisely-does-reset-network-settings-do-on-an-iphone#comment477776_91121)

> **resetting network settings will remove all saved WiFi passwords in iCloud keychain**, effectively deleting remembered WiFi networks from **all your signed in devices**. A workaround: turn off iCloud Keychain, then reset network settings, then turn iCloud Keychain back on. Your saved WiFi networks will then sync back, unharmed.

This is the behavior in devices running iOS 9 and later.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. To be sure, I signed out of iCloud before resetting and that seems to have worked